# How can the momentum of a charged particle in a uniform magnetic field be a gradient?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics

In the Hamilton-Jacobi formalism for a single particle the momentum "field" is written as $\nabla S$, so Hamilton's principle function $S$ is like a potential function for the momentum. However, for a charged particle in a uniform magnetic field the momentum, considered as a vector field, must surely be rotational (or at least have a rotational component), which seems incompatible with being $\nabla S$! How can this be? It seems like it should also have a curl part...

Comment: The expression $\nabla S$ is a function of particle coordinates but at any time $t$ it gives the correct momentum of the rotating particle only if the correct coordinates for this time are used; the values of $\nabla S$ at time $t$ for different values of particle coordinates are bogus. There is no vector field of momentum at any single time, the particle is always at one point of space and since for any time, $\nabla S$ may be a different function of coordinates, its value at the actual position of the particle can give correctly the momentum of the particle even if it is moving in circles.

Comment: Another way of looking at this is that the Hamilton-Jacobi idea is to split the phase space $(q_1,q_2,\dots q_n,p_1,p_2,\dots p_n, t)$ into "sheets" over $(q_1,q_2,\dots q_n)$ identified by $n+1$ or  conserved quantities which must remain the same on the sheet. Now each sheet must contain full trajectories given by Hamilton's equations, but we are essentially stating at the outset that we're going to choose which trajectories to put on one of these sheets by making sure $\nabla\times p=0$ on that sheet, and then we will derive the conserved quantities which separate the sheets *afterwards*.